# Nonhomogeneous Burgers equation weak (or Integral) Solutions and Rankine-Hugoniot

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

We have the following equation the nonhomogeneous Burgers equation with initial condition
\begin{align*}
     uu_x +u_y&= 1\\
u(x,0)&=x\quad x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
corresponding to the manifold  $\Gamma$ in the $xyz$ space given by
\begin{equation}
    x = s,\quad y = 0,\quad z = s
\end{equation}
The characteristic differential equations
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{dx}{dt}=z\quad  \frac{dy}{dt}=1\quad \frac{dz}{dt}=1
\end{equation*}
Integrating each of the expressions we have
\begin{align*}
\int dz&=\int  dt\\
z&=t+f_1(s)
\end{align*}
combined with the initial condition  for $t=0$ lead to the parametric representation
\begin{align*}
z&=t+s
\end{align*}
also
\begin{align*}
\int dy&=\int 1 dt\\
y&=t
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\int dx&=\int z dt\\
\int dx&=\int t+s dt\\
x&=\frac{t^2}{2}+st+s
\end{align*}
therefore the characteristics flowing out from $\Gamma$ are
\begin{equation*}
    X(s,t)=\frac{t^2}{2}+st+s,\quad Y(s,t)=t, \quad Z(s,t)=t+s
\end{equation*}
we find the solution
\begin{equation*}
    u=y+\frac{2x-y^2}{2y+2}
\end{equation*}

**Weak (or Integral) Solutions**

In this case the characteristics are curves that are given as follows
\begin{equation*}
    X(s,t)=\frac{t^2}{2}+st+s
\end{equation*}
that this characteristic presents shock.

I have several questions the first one is how this characteristic presents shock.

a) How find $y_s$ (breaking time) and the location $x_s$?

b) In this case, how is the Rankine-Hugoniot study done?

Your answers would be of great help. Thank you very much. I remain attentive to your answer.

Comment: This topic has already been discussed at length on this site. Please do some research.

Comment: if the exercise has been done with the burger equation but with the one that is equal to zero but when the equation is Nonhomogeneous the study of the characteristics changes a bit